# PHP form submission inside another php form is not working

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to implement one php submission form through another and facing problem but I don't know what it is.
Let me explain:
there is 2 php forms: modify.php and save_modified.php

modify.php - it get's data from html form searches for it db and shows result in save_modified.php file.

```
$sql_search="SELECT * FROM `acronym_table` WHERE `acronym` LIKE '$acronym'";

$result = $conn->query($sql_search);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<form action=\"save_modified.php\" method=\"post\">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" value=". $row["id"]. "></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Acronym</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" value=". $row["acronym"] ."></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td><textarea>".$row["definition"]."</textarea></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type=\"button\" value=\"Modify\"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>";
    }
} else{
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Till now everything is fine. But after, when I change something and try to save it (when I click to "Modify" button) nothing happens. Just for testing purpose content of save_modified.php is

```
<?php
echo"lasdlfajs;dfjas;fj";
?>
```

Can you please help to find out what is my mistake in modify.php?

Comment: You should avoid echo using to display HTML. You should use echo only when it's necessary.

Comment: How else can I display this kind of content, then?

Comment: With ending PHP code with ?> and re start PHP code with <?php.
All code outside <?php and ?> will generate your final HTML file.

Comment: Ok. It's also good technique, but I find my way more easier, don't sure why :) I think I used to it.

Comment: But you loose readability of syntax highlight especially in StackOverflow. Compare your code with Tobias's code. It's just an advice to improve readability of your code. Moreover, you will no longer be obliged to escape your quotes \".

Comment: Of course @jedema, I'm not telling it is not good. But you also understand that it is not easy to change habit. Thank you for advice. I'll try to adapt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button type is wrong. It must be `type="submit`

```
<td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <input type=\"button\" value=\"Modify\"><
> ```
>
> when I click to "Modify" button nothing happens

`<input type="button">` isn't supposed to do anything. It exists so you can bind JavaScript event handlers to it.

If you want to submit the form you need to use a **submit** button or input.

```
<input type="submit" value="Modify">
```

Comment: I guess you know what you're doing :)... But what if you wanted to submit  in the background and show the results, would you personally use Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using some javascript to submit the form, you should change the type of the input from button to submit.

from

```
<input type=\"button\" value=\"Modify\">
```

to

```
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\">
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use "submit" type button

```
<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\">
```